# Browser/viewer to see an R dataset in Azure Notebooks?

Tags: r, azure, jupyter-notebook

I understand that the command line can be used to view data, e.g. head(), tail(), etc.

However, I'd like to view the whole dataset. Is this possible within Jupyter Azure Notebooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Untested) if you have a DataFrame object, calling the name should print the entire dataset.
For example, if your dataframe is named dta, just have

```
dta
```

at the end of a cell, and run that cell.